# Tmux pad format string

Tags: formatting, format, padding, tmux, pad

I want to pad a format string to a certain length. For example, the [Tmux Battery](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-battery) plugin introduces the **`battery_percentage`** format string. I can use this in the status bar as **`#{battery_percentage}`**. The battery percentage values can be:

1. Between 0% and 9% (One Digit).
2. Between 11% and 99% (Two Digits).
3. Exactly 100% (Three Digits).

I want the format string to always be displayed 3 digits, padded with spaces at the end, how can I achieve that?

I saw that there is the format **`#{pN:variable}`** in [this page](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Formats#summary-of-modifiers), but it did not work when I tried to use it with format strings, even though at the end they are variables. Maybe I just did not know how to use it, I don't know...

Comment: @meuh Thanks man, you gave me the key for the solution, I passed the command to awk and padded it there. And put the single command in tmux configuration. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the plugin startup code, [battery.tmux](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-battery/blob/master/battery.tmux), you can see that `${battery_percentage}` is actually converted to `#($CURRENT_DIR/scripts/battery_percentage.sh)`, which is a request to run a script. I don't know if `#{p3:#(...)}` can be made to work since this is not a simple variable.

You could always edit the plugin [shell script](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-battery/blob/master/scripts/battery_percentage.sh) to return the padded string (assuming tmux keeps the leading spaces).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need, and the way I worked around it is by defining a variable that conditionally prepends a space to the percentage if the value of `{battery_percentage}` is not equal to the string literal `100%`.

Here is what I did:

```
justified_battery_pct="#{?#{==:#{battery_percentage},100#{a:37}},#{battery_percentage}, #{battery_percentage}}"
```

A couple things to note:

- because `%` is a special character, I used the `#{a:XYZ}` ASCII replacement mechanism to match on the `%` literal (ASCII code 37 in decimal)
- don't miss the  -literal in the unequal branch ( `#{battery_percentage}`); that's what pads the battery percentage value when it's in the range of [10-99]%

This of course wouldn't work for battery <10%, but I almost never let my battery get that low. And I think you should be able to create something similar following my example, perhaps using the `m/r` regular expression comparison.

---

Edit:

I decided to add the conditional to justify single battery percentage to my config too.

```
battery_pct_not_100p="#{?#{m/r:^[0-9]#{a:37},#{battery_percentage}},  #{battery_percentage}, #{battery_percentage}}"
battery_pct_justified="#{?#{==:#{battery_percentage},100#{a:37}},#{battery_percentage},$battery_pct_not_100p}"
```